# Clip a BufferedImage to an Area

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, clip

I'm trying to draw an image within a certain area. Right now I have code that fills an area with a `RadialGradientPaint`.

```
Area lightArea = ...
// fill the polygon with the gradient paint
g.setPaint(light.paint);
g.fill(lightArea);
```

I would like to draw a `BufferedImage` in that area instead of drawing a `RadialGradientPaint`. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Graphics.setClip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28java.awt.Shape%29):

```
g.setClip(lightArea);
g.drawImage(yourImage, x, y, null);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html for more details.

Comment: And don't forget to 1- reset the clip and 2- check to see if the new clip is still in the bounds of the old one...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `BufferdImage#getSubimage`

```
Rectangle bounds = area.getBounds();
BufferedImage img = master.getSubImage(0, 0, Math.min(bounds.width, master.getWidth()), Math.min(bounds.height, master.getHeight());
```

This assumes that the area is rectangular.  If it's not, you cold create a mask image, based on the shape of the `Area` and use it to generate masked image (cookie cutting the image out of the shape)

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961190/can-i-have-image-alpha-fade-from-left-to-right-in-java/26962173#26962173). The benefit of which is it allows for antialiasing